# Need to fine tune my mysql query having an index on a varchar column

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a table which has nearly **2,000,000** records.
I have a column(crmid) which is a varchar in that table.
I wrote a query 
 say,

```
 Select column1, column2,..... from table where crmid = ?
```

the value comes from the front-end. Previously it was working fine but now it is getting timed-out from front end. 
Then I used an index on that column which even doesn't helped me much.
After indexing I explained the query, again it is traversing **1,800,000 rows** using index too.

Please help me in fine tuning this query.

**Note : This is not the actual query, its just the simplest form. There are many joins in the actual query.**

EDITED ::
The full query is

```
select  column1
        , column2 
from    table1 a
        inner join appointmentstatusmst st 
            on  st.entity_id = a.shdstatuslviid 
        inner join hlcclientdetails 
            on  a.shdclientid = hlcclientdetails.cldregno 
            and a.shdclientdcnid = hlcclientdetails.clddcnid
where   hlcclientdetails.cldunifiedcrmid = ?
```

The explain output is [image]

Comment: You should post your entire query so that we can better assist. Also, run EXPLAIN <your query> to get a query plan, and post that too.

Comment: the actual query has many joins with different tables, only this part of the query is hitting the performance.
Any ways thanks for ur quick response

Comment: If there's another way of tuning this query not even using the index are also welcome.

Comment: Post the whole query, or at least exactly how you are using the `crmid` column in the where clause. btw, 2 million rows is considered a "small to medium" sized table

Comment: Please post your query. Other wise not possible to find exactly.

Comment: Are the fields you are joining on indexed? How many rows does the statement returns?

Comment: @Lieven: yes sir they are indexed, and the number of rows is different for different crmid..

Comment: @SashiKant: Can you post the tables' definitions and the EXPLAIN output?

Comment: This is not the explain output of this query. Be consistent. If this query you have here is slow, then post the explain of this one, not another query's explain plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there an index on `appointmentstatusmst.entityid`?  How about on `table1.shdclientid` and `table1.shdclientdcnid`?  How about on `hlcclientdetails.cldregno` and `hlcclientdetails.clddcnid`?

For your joins to work smoothly, you need indexes on the columns involved in the join criteria as well as on the column you're using to choose output rows.

@Bohemian is correct, this is a medium-sized, not large, problem.

EDIT.

It may help to think through what your mySQL server actually has to do to perform your query.

```
 where hlcclientdetails.cldunifiedcrmid = ?
```

means it has to romp through your `hlcclientdetails` table looking for certain rows.  So an index on `cldunifiedcrmid` will let it do that efficiently.  You've mentioned that you have that index in place.  Good.

Moving on,

```
   inner join hlcclientdetails 
              on  a.shdclientid = hlcclientdetails.cldregno 
             and  a.shdclientdcnid = hlcclientdetails.clddcnid
```

means it has to take the rows it found in your `hlcclientdetails` table and match them to your `table1 a` by looking at `a.shdclientdcnid` and `a.shdclientid`.  So, your query can probably benefit from a compound index in `table1 a` for those two columns.   You should try adding that index, and see whether performance gets better.

Finally,

```
inner join appointmentstatusmst st 
           on  st.entity_id = a.shdstatuslviid
```

means the server has to take the rows it found in `table1 a` and match them up to this third table.  You mentioned in your comment that entity_id is the PK of that table.  That will help.

You get the idea, I hope.  Indexes help not only with WHERE clauses but with ON clauses.

By the way, the full-text index mentioned in another answer won't help with this JOIN performance problem you are having.

Comment: entity_id is the primary key of that table

Comment: As a rule of thumb virtually all foriegn keys need indexes as they are almost always used in joins. I know in SQl server they are not created automatically, I would suspect they are not in my sql either.  I got a kick out of your use of the word romp.